# How to import a subset of polymer icons

Tags: polymer, custom-element

I'm using couple of polymer's iron-icons from each category and would prefer not importing the whole set. is there a possibility (or tooling/plugin for vulcanize) to only import the ones i need? and have a smaller HTML file to serve?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Polymer Iconset Generator](https://poly-icon.appspot.com/) tool to create your own custom subset of the default iron-icons. It's really handy and it sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: this looks really promising, i hoped i could pass the array of the icon names, but i can definitely get the results with the generator. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To import only the one you need you can create your own file custom-icons.html that will have the same base as the iron-icons.html.

You just have to change the 'name' attribute from the `<iron-iconset-svg></iron-iconset-svg>` node to match the custom name you will use. I will use 'custom-icons' you will use this name to insert an icon after.

Your file will looks like this :

```
   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
   <iron-iconset-svg name="custom-icons" size="24">
       <svg>
           <defs>
               .
               .
               .
           </defs>
        </svg>
    </iron-iconset-svg>
```

Inside the `<defs>...</defs>` node you just have to copy from the iron-icons set or from the other icons set (device, editor, notification...) the `<g>` node, that correspond to the icon you want to use, and insert it inside your custom-icons.html file.

For example we want the menu icon from the iron-icons.html file. 
Just copy this element :

```
<g id="menu"><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/></g>
```

and paste it inside the `<defs>...</defs>` node inside your custom file.
You will have this :

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<iron-iconset-svg name="custom-icons" size="24">
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <g id="menu"><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"/></g>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

Now in your application just import this file instead of the iron-icons and use the icon like this :

```
<iron-icon icon="custom-icons:menu"></iron-icon>
```

If you change the 'id' attribute value in the `<g></g>` node (menu2 for example), use it like this :

```
 <iron-icon icon="custom-icons:menu2"></iron-icon>
```

For more details go check the Rob Dodson polycast : [Custom icons with Iron Iconsets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjmRUgUca1g)

Answer (score 0):

You can also download them directly and individually, in the format your want, independently of Polymer, from Google's Material Design website:

https://material.io/icons/

This way you'll get the new added icons, too.